# Finding the matrix $T(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

> "Let $T$ be a linear transformation on the plane with
>
> $$T \begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 3\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and  }\quad T \begin{pmatrix}3\\ 4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}5\\ -4\end{pmatrix}$$
>   Find $T(x)$."

I tried to insert the various values of $T$ into the matrix and managed to set up some equations, but I am not sure how you would generalize the entire thing in terms of $x$.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}= z_1\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}+z_2\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Solve for $z_1$ and $z_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_2$.